# How to "Select Checkbox" in Robot Framework?

Tags: checkbox, robotframework

My app has an option to add something from checkbox. The values to be selected can be different if I sort it by different columns. But when I dont change it, I should be able to select one but despite my several attempts in Robot Framework, I have not been able to select. Can someone please help me with this?

**My outer HTML is:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" tabindex="4">
```

**Xpath is**

```
//*[@id="evidenceListPanel"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/label/input
```

**My script to select checkbox:**

```
Select Checkbox  xpath=//*[@id="evidenceListPanel"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/label/input
```

And it does not select the checkbox. I used this same script for other website and I was able to select checkbox for its not selecting in my app. Any help will be greatly appreciated. TY

Comment: Do you get any errors in the log?

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I think your comment resolved the issue. The error log said, item was not visible. So, I maximized the window size and it worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Open Browser ${URL}   ${Browser}
Maximize Browser Window
Wait Until Element Is Visible ${locator}
Select Checkbox ${locator}
```

this will work, comment and let me know if there is any issues with it.

Comment: Your answer is valid but you should refer comments below question before you answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following way you can select checkbox, provided respective page should be opened in browser.

Select Checkbox id='evidenceListPanel'

or

Click Element id='evidenceListPanel'

And if you want ensure whether  checkbox is selected then can use - Checkbox Should Be Selected  id='evidenceListPanel'

Answer (score 0):

Pratik -

Since you've identified the section with the **id** of `evidenceListPanel`, and *assuming* that there's only one element with attribute `name` being `rememberMe`, this should work:

```
xpath=//*[@id="evidenceListPanel"]//*[@name="rememberMe"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps ensures till visibility of checkbox and then verify whether the page contains expected checkbox then select the same from the page.

```
${locator} = //[id='Gender_checkbox']
```

Wait Until Element Is Visible

```
${locator} Page Should Contain Checkbox  ${locator}
```

Select **`Checkbox`**   `${locator}`